# how to store link in selenium

Tags: java, selenium

Url : http://patft.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO2&Sect2=HITOFF&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsearch-adv.htm&r=0&f=S&l=50&d=PTXT&RS=AANM%2F%22Cognizant%22&Refine=Refine+Search&Query=AANM%2F%22Cognizant+Technology+Solutions%22

Put above url into any browser. After that in that page  links will come.I want to store each link into one key . After clicking that link it will go next page. In that i want to take abstract contents as value . I want to put the above key value pair into hash map. It will iterate till end of link count.I want code .Please help me.

Comment: To use `Select` you need `<select>` tag, not `select` in class attribute. You need to click on the dropdown to open it and then click on your option.

Comment: i tried all the ways. please send me the code to select dropdown menu. i tried using index also. please help me . Above my DOM structure is there.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar Can you consider showcasing your work please? Thanks

Comment: u want code form first line.

Answer (score 0):

What I can see in the dom you have posted , there is no select tag present.
If there would have any select dropdown present  your code would somewhat look like

```
  <select id='abc'>
```

Only in that case your code

```
    Select select = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("abc")));
    select.selectByVisibleText(Value);
```

would work.

Since, it is not a select in your dom. You can achieve selecting options performing 2 clicks

1. clicking on the select dropdown

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 'select']")).click;
2. and next click on the select options

   driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath to otions")).click;